# Backbone.js router initialize function

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm pretty new to backbone.js and am still learning how everything works. I'm trying to understand how the `initialize` option of the backbone router works, and haven't been able to find any good documentation or examples, so I was hoping someone here could help me understand it. I actually have a couple of questions about it...

1. If I define a router with multiple routes, is the `initialize` function called each time one of those routes is called with a call to `router.navigate`??
2. What would be the most appropriate way to delay the execution of a route handler until after initialization has occurred?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I define a router with multiple routes, is the initialize function
>   called each time one of those routes is called with a call to
>   router.navigate??

Think of `initialize` function as `constructor` function you would normally find in other OOP languages or OOP concepts. **Whenever you create a new instance**, the `initialize` function is called. Hence you can put up any initialization code, settings or defaults, etc in that.

> What would be the most appropriate way to delay the execution of a
>   route handler until after initialization has occurred?

You don't need to worry about it, backbone will fire the event at the appropriate time.

Just keep in mind that **`initialize` is called only when you create a new instance of the class.** using `new` keyword.

Comment: OK...that turns out to actually be simpler than I thought it was. I had some other stuff in my code that was problematic that seems to have been making it appear to have been more complicated than that, and I feel a bit foolish now. Thanks for the info, and for clearing that up for me, much appreciated.